# How To Add Custom User Meta During Registration

Tags: php

I am following [this](https://tommcfarlin.com/add-custom-user-meta-during-registration/) tutorial and have entered in the code exactly as shown. The functions work but they are not displaying any information. When I use `var_dump($user_id);` I get this error:

```
object(WP_Error)#1021 (2) {  
   ["errors"]=> array(1) { 
      ["empty_user_login"]=> array(1) { 
          [0]=> string(46) "Cannot create a user with an empty login name." 
      } 
   } 
   ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } 
}
```

but it is not empty. I have also tried to add it as the documentation states for `wp_insert_user()` [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) and I will populate but no information in the zip code. Any suggestions?

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user(
  array(
    'user_login'  => $input['testeroo'],
    'user_pass' => wp_generate_password ( 12, false ),
    'first_name'  => $input['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
    'user_email'  => $input['email_address'],
    'display_name'  => $input['first_name'] . ' ' . $input['last_name'],
    'nickname'  => $input['first_name'] . ' ' . $input['last_name'],
    'role'    => 'None'
  )
);
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'zip_code', $input['zip_code'] );
var_dump($user_id);
```

Comment: Where is `$input` coming from?

Comment: the tutorial you are following seems to be for a custom form, so you can't simply copy and paste those snippets and expect it to do anything, they need to placed in some kind of context.

Comment: Just read carefully the error then you get the clue. and before creating user var_dump your `$input` object variable. and remember user_login field can't be empty when you creating a user. so make sure that `$input['testeroo']` has any value